# Jahia CMS module which provides body html tag

Tags: content-management-system

I read that Jahia CMS uses 960gs framework as default for page layouts, also I read that all divs defining rows should be nested into a "special" div which has class equals to container_16. So I decided to find a module which in its view renders html for that special div. I tried file content search for "container_16" and found a bunch of css files and that's all, no view for any module showed up. And it made me confused and I kinda want to find a module which provides a basic html tages like "body" tag.

Does anybody knows the name of the jahia module

Answer (score 2):

The module you're looking for is called "grid" and the source code is available here : http://subversion.jahia.org/svn/jahia/trunk/modules/grid/

Inside the row.jsp file you will find the following div :

<div class="container_16">